# Php block not working when i am trying to fetching data

Tags: php, mysql

This is code which is trying to fetching data from DB. but getting error `mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter`.

```
<?php
    $sql="select * from admin_slider where status_name=1 and (end_date>=CURDATE() or unlimited=1)order by position asc";
    $result_set=mysql_query($sql);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
    {
?>
<div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;">
    <img data-u="image" src="images/slideruploads/<?php echo $row['file'];?>" />
</div>
<?php  } ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Comment: run this query in php myadmin.. chk r u getting results or not. select * from admin_slider where status_name=1 and (end_date>=CURDATE() or unlimited=1)order by position asc

Comment: first stop using `mysql_*` deprecated now. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. also add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` just after `<?php` and check once what other problems are there in your code

Comment: yes i run the query it run currectly @devpro

Comment: where i can place mysql_*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your query. So $result_set is not a mysql resource any more. mysql_fetch_array() expectes parameter to be an mysql resource. But in your case it is not resource.
Corrected the syntax.

```
<?php
    $sql="SELECT * 
            FROM  admin_slider 
           WHERE  status_name=1 
             AND ( end_date>=CURDATE() OR unlimited=1)
        ORDER BY position ASC";
    $result_set = mysql_query($sql) or (die(mysql_error()));
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) {
?>
        <div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" 
                 src="images/slideruploads/<?php echo $row['file'];?>" />
       </div>
       <?php
    }
?>
```

Also note: mysql_query is depreciated. Move to PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Dinesh your code execute but when enter while loop it will false

Comment: nope Dinesh. just stopped, i think while not executed,

Comment: ya because there is no result found, that's  why the while loop is not executed.  try to print mysql_num_rows( $result_set); to get how many rows has been fetched .  Print after this statement $result_set = mysql_query($sql) or (die(mysql_error()));